# Using RegEx in JSON Schema

Tags: regex, json, schema, jsonschema

Trying to write a JSON schema that uses RegEx to validate a value of an item.

Have an item named **progBinaryName** whose value should adhrere to this RegEx string `"^[A-Za-z0-9 -_]+_Prog\\.(exe|EXE)$"`.

Can not find any tutorials or examples that actually explain the use of RegEx in a JSON schema.

Any help/info would be GREATLY appreciated!

Thanks,
D

JSON SCHEMA

```
{
    "name": "string",
    "properties": {
        "progName": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Program Name",
            "required": true
        },
        "ID": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Identifier",
            "required": true
        },
        "progVer": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Version number",
            "required": true
        },
        "progBinaryName": {
            "type": "string",
            "description": "Actual name of binary",
            "patternProperties": {
                "progBinaryName": "^[A-Za-z0-9 -_]+_Prog\\.(exe|EXE)$"
            },
            "required": true
        }
    }
}
```

ERRORS:

Warning! Better check your JSON.

Instance is not a required type - http://json-schema.org/draft-03/hyper-schema#

---

Schema is valid JSON, but not a valid schema.

---

Validation results: failure

```
[ {
    "level" : "warning",
    "schema" : {
        "loadingURI" : "#",
        "pointer" : ""
    },
    "domain" : "syntax",
    "message" : "unknown keyword(s) found; ignored",
    "ignored" : [ "name" ]
}, {
    "level" : "error",
    "domain" : "syntax",
    "schema" : {
        "loadingURI" : "#",
        "pointer" : "/properties/ID"
    },
    "keyword" : "required",
    "message" : "value has incorrect type",
    "expected" : [ "array" ],
    "found" : "boolean"
}, {
    "level" : "error",
    "domain" : "syntax",
    "schema" : {
        "loadingURI" : "#",
        "pointer" : "/properties/progBinaryName"
    },
    "keyword" : "required",
    "message" : "value has incorrect type",
    "expected" : [ "array" ],
    "found" : "boolean"
}, {
    "level" : "error",
    "schema" : {
        "loadingURI" : "#",
        "pointer" : "/properties/progBinaryName/patternProperties/progBinaryName"
    },
    "domain" : "syntax",
    "message" : "JSON value is not a JSON Schema: not an object",
    "found" : "string"
}, {
    "level" : "error",
    "domain" : "syntax",
    "schema" : {
        "loadingURI" : "#",
        "pointer" : "/properties/progName"
    },
    "keyword" : "required",
    "message" : "value has incorrect type",
    "expected" : [ "array" ],
    "found" : "boolean"
}, {
    "level" : "error",
    "domain" : "syntax",
    "schema" : {
        "loadingURI" : "#",
        "pointer" : "/properties/progVer"
    },
    "keyword" : "required",
    "message" : "value has incorrect type",
    "expected" : [ "array" ],
    "found" : "boolean"
} ]
```

---

```
Problem with schema#/properties/progBinaryName/patternProperties/progBinaryName : Instance is not a required type
Reported by http://json-schema.org/draft-03/hyper-schema#
Attribute "type" (["object"])
```

Comment: What is not working? (You might want to put that hyphen at the end of the character class)

Comment: Any online validation does not work right.

Comment: What does "does not work right" mean? Do you get false positives? Do you get false negatives? Do you get some kind of error?

Comment: Validation fails with errors.   http://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/syntax.jsp       http://jsonschemavalidator.herokuapp.com/      http://jsonschemalint.com/ Too many to list.

Comment: Don't you think it might help potential answerers if you included those error messages in the question?

Comment: Example repo https://github.com/rofrol/ajv-regexp-errormessage-example

Answer (score 73, accepted):

To test a string value (not a property name) against a RegEx, you should use the `"pattern"` keyword:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "progBinaryName": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^[A-Za-z0-9 -_]+_Prog\\.(exe|EXE)$"
        }
    }
}
```

P.S. - if you want the pattern to match the *key* for the property (not the value), then you should use `"patternProperties"` (it's like `"properties"`, but the key is a RegEx).

Comment: Is it possible to have case insensitive pattern matching?

Comment: @Ninja it seems it can be done only via properly designed regular expression. Check https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/regular_expressions.html - usage of flags is not within recommended RegExp syntax for JSON Schema due to  interoperability reasons.

Comment: @Ninja for cace insensitive look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41874810/make-json-schema-pattern-case-insensitive/65673578#65673578

Answer (score 14):

Your JSON schema syntax is incorrect. Change

```
"patternProperties": {
    "progBinaryName": "^[A-Za-z0-9 -_]+_Prog\\.(exe|EXE)$"
    }
```

to

```
"patternProperties": {
    "^[A-Za-z0-9 -_]+_Prog\\.(exe|EXE)$": {}
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer and not wasting my time. Much, much appreciated!

Comment: Wasn't the question was about testing the *value*, not the property name?