# JSON schema string

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

I was trying to validate a particular field in an JSON request file.

the field should be between 1-160 characters in length and should NOT allow any special characters .

I tried the below . But it does not work . Any inputs will be deeply appreciated.

```
"SMSContent": {
              "id": "http://jsonschema.net/Request/Data/SMSContent",
              "type": "string",
               "pattern": "[a-zA-Z]{1,160}"
              }
```

Comment: I also tried the below . does not work :(

"SMSContent": {
              "id": "http://jsonschema.net/Request/Data/SMSContent",
              "type": "string",
              "minLength": 1,
              "maxLength": 160,
               "pattern":  "[0-9A-Za-z]{1,160}"
            }

Comment: Have you tried without `{1,160}` since you are using `minLength` and `maxLength`?  Not all regex implementation support the {n,m} notation.  That could be the problem you are running into.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using RegEx in JSON Schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16491973/using-regex-in-json-schema)

Comment: You need to add a $ to indicate the end of the string like this:

"pattern": "[a-zA-Z]{1,160}$"