# make json schema pattern case insensitive

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

in my json schema i made a definition for "colors" like this

```
{
    "colors": {
        "type":"string",
        "pattern": "AliceBlue|AntiqueWhite|Aqua|Aquamarine|Azure|Beige|Bisque|Black|BlanchedAlmond|Blue|BlueViolet|Brown|BurlyWood|CadetBlue|Chartreuse|Chocolate|Coral|CornflowerBlue|Cornsilk|Crimson|Cyan|DarkBlue|DarkCyan|DarkGoldenRod|DarkGray|DarkGrey|DarkGreen|DarkKhaki|DarkMagenta|DarkOliveGreen|DarkOrange|DarkOrchid|DarkRed|DarkSalmon|DarkSeaGreen|DarkSlateBlue|DarkSlateGray|DarkSlateGrey|DarkTurquoise|DarkViolet|DeepPink|DeepSkyBlue|DimGray|DimGrey|DodgerBlue|FireBrick|FloralWhite|ForestGreen|Fuchsia|Gainsboro|GhostWhite|Gold|Gray|Grey|Green|GreenYellow|HoneyDew|HotPink|IndianRed|Indigo|Ivory|Khaki|Lavender|LavenderBlush|LawnGreen|LemonChiffon|LightBlue|LightCoral|LightCyan|LightGoldenRodYellow|LightGray|LightGrey|LightGreen|LightPink|LightSalmon|LightSeaGreen|LightSkyBlue|LightSlateGray|LightSlateGrey|LightSteelBlue|LightYellow|Lime|LimeGreen|Linen|Magenta|Maroon|MediumAquaMarine|MediumBlue|MediumOrchid|MediumPurple|MediumSeaGreen|MediumSlateBlue|MediumSpringGreen|MediumTurquoise|MediumVioletRed|MidnightBlue|MintCream|MistyRose|Moccasin|NavajoWhite|Navy|OldLace|Olive|OliveDrab|Orange|OrangeRed|Orchid|PaleGoldenRod|PaleGreen|PaleTurquoise|PaleVioletRed|PapayaWhip|PeachPuff|Peru|Pink|Plum|PowderBlue|Purple|RebeccaPurple|Red|RosyBrown|RoyalBlue|SaddleBrown|Salmon|SandyBrown|SeaGreen|SeaShell|Sienna|Silver|SkyBlue|SlateBlue|SlateGray|SlateGrey|Snow|SpringGreen|SteelBlue|Tan|Teal|Thistle|Tomato|Turquoise|Violet|Wheat|White|WhiteSmoke|Yellow|YellowGreen"
    }
}
```

how can i make this pattern case insensitive?

thanks

Comment: No way to do it within the specification. This could be helpful though: https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv-keywords#regexp

Comment: what do you intend to make case-insensitive actually? the values of the key `pattern`? convert them to lowercase and do the comparison on lowercased values, for instance.

Comment: i want that json schema validates both if i write "red" or "Red" as colors

Comment: You can add red and Red both in pattern. By keeping it case insensitive you would be allowing rEd,rED or RED which you may not like.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pattern='^(?i)(AliceBlue|AntiqueWhite)$'`

like that you can use.

```
aliceblue - pass

antIquEWhiTe - pass

Black - fail
```

Comment: This may not work with all implementations. For example, https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator gives an error saying it "is not a valid ECMA 262 regular expression".

Comment: I got a similar error to @SerpC using both [https://json-schema.hyperjump.io/](https://json-schema.hyperjump.io/) and [https://jsonschema.dev/](https://jsonschema.dev/) .

Comment: I have tried in https://jsonschema.dev/ it is working
JSON SChema
`{ 
  "colors": {
        "type": "string",
        "pattern": "^(?i)(AliceBlue|AntiqueWhite)$"
    }  
}`
JSON Validation
`{
  "colors" : "aliceBlue"
}`

Answer (score 4):

We can achieve the case insensitive for the anum using pattern. However json schema doesn't support "/i" for regex insensitive. So we can achieve with our own regular expressions pattern without using /i.

Enum :

month: { type: 'string', enum: ['may', 'June', 'July'] },

Regex pattern:

month: { type: 'string',  pattern: '^([Mm][Aa][Yy]|[Jj][Uu][Nn][Ee]|
[Jj][Uu][Ll[Yy])$',},

we have used the above pattern for fastify schema validation for input parameter.

Comment: As unelegant as this answer seems it is what worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Use ajv-keywords for that:

```js
import Ajv from 'ajv';
import AjvKeywords from 'ajv-keywords';
// ajv-errors needed for errorMessage
import AjvErrors from 'ajv-errors';

const ajv = new Ajv.default({ allErrors: true });

AjvKeywords(ajv, "regexp");
AjvErrors(ajv);

// modification of regex by requiring Z https://www.regextester.com/97766
const ISO8601UTCRegex = /^(-?(?:[1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]{4})-(1[0-2]|0[1-9])-(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])T(2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(.[0-9]+)?Z$/;

const typeISO8601UTC = {
  "type": "string",
  "regexp": ISO8601UTCRegex.toString(),
  "errorMessage": "must be string of format 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Got ${0}",
};

const schema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    foo: { type: "number", minimum: 0 },
    timestamp: typeISO8601UTC,
  },
  required: ["foo", "timestamp"],
  additionalProperties: false,
};

const validate = ajv.compile(schema);

const data = { foo: 1, timestamp: "2020-01-11T20:28:00" }

if (validate(data)) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
} else {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(validate.errors, null, 2));
}
```

https://github.com/rofrol/ajv-regexp-errormessage-example

Answer (score -3):

You can create an enum class for pattern which stores all the pattern values. Then create an annotation which results true for any value you have in pattern; and while putting the condition for check do  `var1.equalsignorecase(var2)`.

Annotation will be put on the class which is using it.

```
Class colour {
  Private string type;
  @mycustomannotation
  Private string pattern;
}
```